# Asp.net dynamic dropdownlist

Tags: c#, asp.net, drop-down-menu, viewstate

I want to create a dynamic `DropDownList` in ASP.NET, but after postback the `DropDownList` loses the selected value. Recreating the control on postback has no effect (ViewState, same ID).

Im wondering if the ViewState of the `DropDownList` is not working. I've created dynamic TextBoxes before, and they retain the value after postback.

I'm thinking to get the value from the form post like in this article:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Creating-Dynamic-DropDownList-Controls-in-ASP.Net.aspx

Is this a common solution to this problem?

Comment: When are you recreating the control? Load or Init?

Comment: Could you post your code please?  It is a lot easier to find the problem if we don't have to guess.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're not, you should be dynamically creating the drop-down on Init, and then you can read/write their properties on or after Load.  Have a look at this article: https://web.archive.org/web/20210330142645/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/092904-1.aspx which describes it in more detail.

Answer (score 0):

You have to recreate the control before ViewState is loaded, like during `OnInit` or `OnPreInit` for example. You also need to assign the same ID to the control every time the page is posted back, because ViewState uses the control ID to reload the values.